# Django def_get logic in models.py not finding object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to save a field `profit` to the model `ItemSold`.

I need to get `purchase_price` from the previous `Item` model in order to save `profit` in the `def get_profit` function in the `ItemSold` model (`OneToOne` with `Item`).

The `def_get_profit` is in `models.py` because I am only using the Django admin dashboard at the moment to view / edit records.

I am getting the `DoesNotExist` error which is obviously being caused by `purchase_price = Item.objects.get(id=self.id).purchase_price` as when I remove it, the function works.

I'd be grateful if someone could help me understand why `id=self.id` isn't recognising the `Item.object` in question.

**models.py**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    purchase_price = models.FloatField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

class ItemSold(models.Model):
    sold_price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    profit = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def get_profit(self):
        purchase_price = Item.objects.get(id=self.id).purchase_price
        sold_price = float(self.sold_price)
        fees = float((sold_price * 0.09) + (0.9))
        profit = float(sold_price - purchase_price - fees)
        return profit

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.profit = self.get_profit
        super(ItemSold, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.profit

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.profit}'
```

Comment: Sorry for being totally unrelated to the topic, but what's the advantage of using @property on a model method? (I'm curious because i've never used it)

Comment: @RicardoVilaça I just copied this code over from another project I was working on and forgot to take it off, but I'm not sure the advantage..I'm going to look into if there is any now..

Comment: @RicardoVilaça you may find this interesting but when I remove the @property, I get the error `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replace:

```
purchase_price = Item.objects.get(id=self.id).purchase_price
```

with:

```
purchase_price = Item.objects.get(id=self.item.id).purchase_price
```

The reason why self.id is not working is because, in this case, self refers to ItemSold. While in your `Item.objects` you want to have `Item`'s id.

For example, your `ItemSold` is the 4th item sold so far. But, it is the first `Item` in your database. You want to get `Item`'s id in `Item.objedcts.get`.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestion. It works :) So is that because `self.id` isn't finding the specific `object` which then gets solved by adding `item`?

Comment: hi, I updated my answer with a short explanation. does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. Perfect...thank you.